# passings array as props in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react.

I have been experimenting on react and I got stuck on how to pass array using props.

case-1:

```
var c = ['program'];
var Navigation = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            openDropdown: -1
        };
    },
    getDefaultProps: function () {
        return {
            config: ['everyone']
        };
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="navigation">
                helloworld {this.props.config[0]};
            </div>
            );
    }
});

React.render(<Navigation config={c}/>, document.body);
```

This is rendering helloworld program. which is expected.

Later I have tried.

**case-2:**

```
var c = ['program'];
var Navigation = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            openDropdown: -1
        };
    },
    getDefaultProps: function () {
        return {
            config: ['everyone']
        };
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="navigation">
              {this.props.config} helloworld ;
            </div>
            );
    }
});

React.render(<Navigation config="React"/>, document.body);
```

This is rendering React helloworld. which is expected as there are no propType defined.

next I have tried.

**case-3 :**

```
var c = ['program'];
var Navigation = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            openDropdown: -1
        };
    },
    getDefaultProps: function () {
        return {
            config: ['everyone']
        };
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="navigation">
                helloworld {this.props.config[0]};
            </div>
            );
    }
});

React.render(<Navigation config=['!!!'] />, document.body);
```

Which is not rendering anything.

Later when I have changed the `React.render(<Navigation config=['!!!'] />, document.body);` to `React.render(<Navigation config={['!!!']} />, document.body);`

it rendered helloworld !!!

I have read in some tutorial that curly braces are used to pass variables so that JSX will know that they are external variable.

But why is case-3 not working with out explicit curly braces though the array is made during the call and why is it working for the case-2 where the string is made inline.

When exactly are the curly braces used?

And it would help me if some one can point me to any good book or online tutorials on react.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34802882/passing-array-to-component-property-in-react

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The curly braces **only** need to be used within JSX elements. Like this:

```
<MyComponent somProp={['something']} />
```

In the case above, the `{}` is the way of saying: "Evaluate the expression that I passed within and pass it as a prop". Within the `{}` you can pass **any** valid JavaScript object or expression. Note that if you pass a string, and specifically for strings, you don't need the curly braces... like `<MyComponent somProp="something" />`.

The above code is the equivalent of this:

```
var myArray = ['something'];
<MyComponent somProp={myArray} />
```

Answer (score 7):

You actually don't need to specify `PropTypes` at all to use props. It's just a good way to document and verify prop types during development.

You are using the `{}` correctly. `{}` will return the value of the expression inside.

**However,** `{['everyone']}` doesn't make much sense. Here you are asking React to return the value of the array itself, rather than one of the elements/values within the array.

To get the first value out of your array, you should be doing: `{this.props.config[0]}` since the value "everyone" is at the 0 index of the array.

If your array had multiple values, you would do something along the lines of:

```
render: function() {
  var values = this.props.config.map(function(value, i){
    return (
      <p>value</p>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className="navigation">
      helloworld {values};
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you truly to mean to actually print out the array itself, and not a particular value within it, you have two good options:

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <div className="navigation">
      helloworld {this.props.config.toString()};
    </div>
  );
}
```

Or

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <div className="navigation">
      helloworld {JSON.stringify(this.props.config)};
    </div>
  );
}
```