# Passing array to component property in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I pass an array to a component as a property. Neither of the following achieve what I am looking for. I want to pass the array of items through, manipulate them in the component and output in the render method.

```
<List columns=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'] /> // unexpected token
<List columns="['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']" /> // passed through as string not array
```

Is there a standard syntax or best practice for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to use `{}` around js expressions:

```
<List columns={['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']} />
```