# React: How to pass an array as props and render a list of images?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend

I am new to react. I want to loop images list(Json) and show these images on screen. So I want to create a prop with Array. But I don't know how to pass Array as props? Would you help take a look?

```
var images = [
  "./resources/bgdefault.jpg",
  "./resources/bg1.jpg",
  "./resources/bg2.jpg",
  "./resources/bg3.jpg",
  "./resources/bg4.jpg",
  "./resources/bg5.jpg",
  "./resources/bg6.jpg",
  "./resources/bg7.jpg",
  "./resources/bg8.jpg"
];

type State = {
  index: number;
};

type Props = {
  backgroundDuration: number;
  imagePath: Array<string>;
};

export class BackgroundImage extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  timerID: number;

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      index: -1
    };
    this.timerID=0;
  }

.....

  render() {
    const path:string = images[this.state.index];
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
          backgroundSize: "cover",
          backgroundImage: `url(${path})`
        }}
      ></div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, refer this it has already been asnwered - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883601/passings-array-as-props-in-reactjs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [passings array as props in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883601/passings-array-as-props-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass any javascript variable to a **prop**. So for example, if you want to loop through an **array** of URLs and render an `img` tag for each:

```
// ImageList.js file

function ImageList (props) {
  const { images } = props

  return <div>{ images.map(imgUrl => <img src={imgUrl} />) }</div>
}
```

And in the parent component you'd have something like:

```
// App.js file

import ImageList from './ImageList'

function App () {
  const images = [
    "./resources/bgdefault.jpg",
    "./resources/bg1.jpg",
    "./resources/bg2.jpg",
    "./resources/bg3.jpg",
    "./resources/bg4.jpg",
    "./resources/bg5.jpg",
    "./resources/bg6.jpg",
    "./resources/bg7.jpg",
    "./resources/bg8.jpg"
  ]

  return <ImageList images={images} />
}
```

This example uses **function** components, but props and JSX work the same way with **class** components (just use `this.props` instead of `props`).

Answer (score 0):

For rendering components based on a list or an array, you should use the javascript .map function, here you have the react docs about this:

https://es.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.htmlhttps://es.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Sorry for the posting the link, I'm using my phone right now. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any type of JavaScript value as a prop:

```
<BackgroundImage imagePath={images} backgroundDuration={5000}/>
```

Your render function then accesses the prop as any other prop:

```
const path:string = this.props.imagePath[this.state.index];
return (
  <div
    style={{
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      backgroundSize: "cover",
      backgroundImage: `url(${path})`
    }}
  ></div>
);
```